# creating web service for querying TFS

Tags: web-services, tfs, console

I have been tasked with creating a web service(usingVS2010) to query TFS (2010) by the workitem number. The user would access the web service, then type in the workitem number and project name and hit a go button.  This would call the web service, retrieve the title, and description and display it for the user on a seperate application. So starting this process I thought I would create a simple console application that does the same thing.  I was able to connect to the server and I am able to see the collection of project that exists.  What I am looking for is some help in querying the Server so that I can type in a number and get a response in my console.   Does anyone have any examples, or direction or websites?  While I wait for an answer I will be searching the web. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [TFS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to query work items programmatically.

Ewald Hoffman has posted an excellent example of how to get a work item by ID:

1. [Part One](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/12/03/TFS-SDK-2010-e28093-Part-1-e28093-Get-the-Team-Project-Collection.aspx) discusses how to get connected to your server
2. [Part Two](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/12/11/TFS-SDK-2010-e28093-Part-2-Get-a-work-item.aspx) shows how to query for a work item by ID.